# Change Screen Resolution windows 8.1 in VIrtualBox

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, virtualbox, display, resolution

I have installed windows 8.1 in Virtual box., I need to change Screen resolution like **1920*1080** , BUt my system **show only upto 1366*660**  I follw this link to change the resolution.http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/5572-screen-resolution-set-displays-windows-8-a.html

But, I dont have any **other display option** only have "**Generic-Pnp Moniter**". I try to update the driver, after update also show same resolutions.

---

Reference:

[image]

Suggest me how to add Other display option to change Resolution like 1920*1080

Comment: You have installed your GPU drivers and the VirtualBox extension drivers I presume?

Comment: @Ramhound No,  I am not installed any GPU  driver and I installed only virtual box guest addition

Comment: Have a look at installing virtual box tools. It is a virtual disk you can insert into the OS and run. Just like VMtools in VMWare.

Comment: @Rajkumar.E - You should install it.